# Cannot install python bottle on linux

Tags: python, bottle

I'm having trouble installing `python bottle` framework on linux. Here is the information I got from `uname -a`:

> Linux magzilla 3.2.0-38-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:18:21 UTC
>   2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have installed `python 2.7.3` and `pip` on it. They both are set up successfully. After I downloaded `bottle 0.11` framework, I tried to install it, using `sudo apt-get install python-bottle`, and I got the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-bottle Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done You
might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following
packages have unmet dependencies:  linux-server : Depends:
linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.39.47) but 3.2.0.53.63 is to be
installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no
packages (or specify a solution).
root@magzilla:/home/llina/bottle-0.11.6# sudo apt-get install
python-bottle Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f
install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet
dependencies:  linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (=
3.2.0.39.47) but 3.2.0.53.63 is to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I tried `apt-get -f install`, but got the result below. Does anyone have a clue on what may be happening?

---

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-32 linux-headers-3.2.0-33 linux-headers-3.2.0-34
  linux-headers-3.2.0-35 linux-headers-3.2.0-36 linux-headers-3.2.0-34-generic
  linux-headers-3.2.0-32-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic
  linux-headers-3.2.0-33-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-36-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-server linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic linux-image-server
  linux-server
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.2.0 linux-source-3.2.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
3 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 603 not upgraded.
14 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 150 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 577932 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic_3.2.0-57.87_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic_3.2.0-57.87_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic_3.2.0-57.87_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 5):

"No space left on device"

Your partition may be full.

See this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/317763/apt-get-no-space-left-on-device-12-04